# Retrieve value from a form and write to a file

Tags: html, forms, perl

i have a form named

> index.cgi

and a configuration file named

> video.start

After the user select from the drop down menu and press submit, the value will be read and write into the configuration file. Here is a snippet from my form:

```
<tr><td>
<form method="POST" action="index.cgi">
<table>
<tr><th colspan="2">Video</th></tr>
<tr><td align="right"><b>Video Source :</b></td><td align="left">
<select name="channel1" size="1">
<option value="/dev/video0">/dev/video0</option>
<option value="/dev/video1">/dev/video1</option>
<option value="/dev/video2">/dev/video2</option>
<option value="/dev/video3">/dev/video3</option>
</select>
</td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<div id="button">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</div>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
```

and here is the code from `index.cgi`:

```
my $file = "video.start";

open (my $in, "+<", $file);
open (my $out, "+<", $file);

my $a = CGI->new();
$video = $a->param('channel1');

while(<$in>)
{
    print $out $_;
    last if $.==3;
}

while(my $data = <$in>)   
{
    #logic

    print $out $data;
    last if $.==5;
}
```

Finally, here is what my configuration file looks like:

```
#Only change at [udp://#] segment 
#This config file is for video

ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -s qvga -r 30 -qscale 5 -an -flags low_delay -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -maxrate 750k -bufsize 3000k -rtbufsize 300k -f h264 udp://#
```

If you can see from the configuration form, after the user submitted the value, the **/dev/video0** will change in the configuration file according to the value submitted by the user. But how can i achieve this in my logic?

Comment: Rather than fiddle with the configuration file (could go sour because out of disk, or whatever) simply create four static configuration files and use the one the user selected.

Comment: But i still can write into the same file right? @tripleee

Comment: You can but I'm saying don't do it.  (Why do you need a separate file for this, anyway?)

Comment: i have updated my question. I have only two files in this. The first one is a form and the second one is the configuration file. I just doesnt know about the logic to achieve what i want to achieve. I had tried everything but still didn't get what i want. @tripleee

Comment: Or maybe i didn't explain this quite right?

Comment: Granted, your question isn't entirely clear, but my interpretation is that you want your Perl script to modify the `video.start` file.  Instead, use `video.start0` if the user selects `/dev/video0` , `video.start1` if the user selects `/dev/video1`, etc.  Editing files on disk is brittle; having four near-identical static files already on the disk to choose from avoids a number of problems, even though it is not entirely elegant.  If you can tell us how these files are used, we may be able to tell you how to avoid using files for this at all.

Comment: But this is a must requirement from my lecturer. Having four configuration files is not allowed at all. The lecturer want us to modify the file given only. Its an assigment given to us. I have tried many logic to change the **/dev/video0** in the configuration file after retrieve value from the form and still did not work. Could you help me how to solve this? @tripleee

Comment: The code from the **index.cgi** is in the form as well @tripleee

Comment: No I think he wants either value selected, be it '/dev/video1' '/dev/video2' '/dev/video3', to be update the 'video.start' file with this new path to video directory. Is this right? If you say yes, I'll write up some quick Perl to do that.

Comment: the value that is retrieve from the form will update the value **/dev/video0** inside the configuration file (**video.start**). For example the value sent is **/dev/video2** and retrieve that value and change the value inside the **video.start** file. So from **/dev/video0** will change into **/dev/video2** .

Comment: Can it be done? because it is in a string @i.ngen-io-us

Comment: Yes it can, let me see if I can concoct something for you, but certainly you can simply overwrite the string within the file, no problem.

Comment: Really? but i've tried so many times still didn't get anything. Your help would be appreciate it @i.ngen-io-us Humanity restored!

Comment: Here are a few ways of getting that done: 

http://perlmaven.com/how-to-replace-a-string-in-a-file-with-perl

I suggest going with one of the CPAN module options, considering the are much easier to work with. And by CPAN module, I am referring to anything with double colons such as the 'Path::Tiny' or 'File::Slurp' examples. More info about CPAN and to search for modules that may also be of great help, run on over to CPAN with a search in tow for 'filehandle':

http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=all&query=filehandle

Comment: Wait. let me try them first. @i.ngen-io-us

Comment: Ok. I still can't manage to do it @i.ngen-io-us (T_T)

Answer (score 0):

The biggest trick to this is that you need to [`flock`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) your files before editing them so there isn't a race condition.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Fcntl qw(:flock);

open my $fh, '<+', 'foobar.txt';
flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die "Cannot lock mailbox - $!\n";
```

After that, just read [`How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f).   I personally would go with `Tie::File` as I think that's probably the easiest way to edit a file in this context.

Comment: So i have to install those plugins? @Miller

Comment: no, `flock` and `Tie::File` are both core.  In retrospect `Tie::File` might be a little too complicated, but there are plenty of other methods recommended in that link I gave you if it became too much.

Comment: but i want to change only the **/dev/video0** after retrieved the value from the form. Is the answer you gave me possible in doing that? @Miller