# Read a specific word in a file PERL using regex

Tags: regex, perl, gentoo

I have a configuration file name `movie.conf` and i want to read a specific word in this file. The configuration file looks like this :

```
#This is a movie setting
#Read only the movie source

ffmpeg -f movie4linux2 -i /folder/movie1 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -s qvga -r 30 -qscale 5 -an -flags low_delay -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -maxrate 750k -bufsize 3000k -rfbufsize 300k -f h264
```

How can i only reads only the `/folder/movie1` part by using regex? Can anybody show me how. I know using `split` can be done. But what if i want to use only regex on this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236840/retrieve-value-from-a-form-and-write-to-a-file

Comment: The near-duplicate seems to be another student at the same course.  It has multiple significant additional complexities which are not present in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (/^ffmpeg.*-i\s+(\S+)/) {
    print $1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/regex/ {print $5}' movie.conf
```

will serve your purpose I suppose

then you can pipe the result to check the regex you want.

suppose your file is :

```
ffmpeg -f movie4linux2 -i /folder/movie2 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -s qvga -r 30 -qscale 5 -an -flags low_delay -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -maxrate 750k -bufsize 3000k -rfbufsize 300k -f h264
ffmpeg -f movie4linux2 -i /folder/movie2 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -s qvga -r 30 -qscale 5 -an -flags low_delay -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -maxrate 750k -bufsize 3000k -rfbufsize 300k -f h264
ffmpeg -f movie4linux2 -i /folder/movie1 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -s qvga -r 30 -qscale 5 -an -flags low_delay -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -maxrate 750k -bufsize 3000k -rfbufsize 300k -f h264
ffmpeg -f movie4linux2 -i /folder/movie3 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -s qvga -r 30 -qscale 5 -an -flags low_delay -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -maxrate 750k -bufsize 3000k -rfbufsize 300k -f h264
```

list of 4 lines.

i use the command :

```
awk '/movie2/ {print $5}' sonew
```

output :

```
/folder/movie2
/folder/movie2
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this using regex? @aelor

Comment: yes ofcourse if you want to add regex , check my update

Comment: @Rockster I think I interpreted your question wrongly :(

Comment: Yeah thats why your answer looks weird. Haha. Thanks for your help btw dude.

Answer (score 0):

Rockster, this simple regex does the trick:

```
@result = $subject =~ m!/\w+!sg;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can try this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
    #read the contents of movie.conf to $string
    open my $fh, '<', "movie.conf";
    read $fh, my $string, -s $fh; 
    close $fh;

    #match the movie path
    if ($string =~ m!(/.*?/\w+)!si) { 
        $result = $1;
    } else {
        $result = "";
    }
    print $result;
```